# Any scripture other than Chaitanya Charitamrita that confirms that He is verily Lord Sri Krishna?

Tags: krishna, gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, iskcon

hare krishna.

I am new to ISKCON culture, but believe strongly that Lord Sri Krishna is the Supreme Personality of Godhead. I am yet to read any work of Srila Prabhupada completely. Since it is essential to have complete faith in the acharyas before setting out on the spiritual path laid out by them, I would like to get my query clarified, and hope that this forum will be able to shed light on it:

My limited experience with various Gaudiya Vaishnava literature has informed me that Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is considered by His followers verily as Lord Sri Krishna Himself. But while Srimad Bhagavatam mentions Kalki avatar as the Lord's next incarnation in the Kali yuga, I have not heard of any prediction regarding the advent of the Lord in the form of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu in any discussion. Is there any scripture other than Chaitanya Charitamrita that mentions Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu as verily Lord Sri Krishna?

I am a believer that Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu is a pure devotee of the Lord, but am finding it difficult to believe that he is the Lord Himself. And this is holding me up from proceeding forward from completely accepting Gaudiya Vaishnavism. Kindly mention any scripture other than Chaitanya Charitamrita that confirms Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu as Lord Sri Krishna.

I apologise if I have ruffled any feathers, but I submit that I ask the question in all sincerity.

Comment: Hare Krishna, may be following help you: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37320/what-are-the-scriptural-evidences-suggesting-chaitanya-mahaprabhu-was-the-incarn

Comment: hare krishna. the post was indeed useful. i intend to read Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu ki Svayam Bhagavatta by Radha Govinda Nath to know more on this.

Comment: your link is identical to that given by @Hare Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Simad Bhagavatam 7.9.38

itthaṁ nṛ-tiryag-ṛṣi-deva-jhaṣāvatārair
lokān vibhāvayasi haṁsi jagat pratīpān
dharmaṁ mahā-puruṣa pāsi yugānuvṛttaṁ
channaḥ kalau yad abhavas tri-yugo 'tha sa tvam

In this way, my Lord, You appear in various incarnations as a human being, an animal, a great saint, a demigod, a fish or a tortoise, thus maintaining the entire creation in different planetary systems and killing the demoniac principles. According to the age, O my Lord, You protect the principles of religion. In the Age of Kali, however, You do not assert Yourself as the Supreme Personality of Godhead, and therefore You are known as Triyuga, or the Lord who appears in three yugas.

Srimad Bhagavatam 11.5.32

kṛṣṇa-varṇaṁ tviṣākṛṣṇaṁ
sāṅgopāṅgāstra-pārṣadam
yajñaiḥ saṅkīrtana-prāyair
yajanti hi su-medhasaḥ

In the Age of Kali, intelligent persons perform congregational chanting to worship the incarnation of Godhead who constantly sings the names of Kṛṣṇa. Although His complexion is not blackish, He is Kṛṣṇa Himself. He is accompanied by His associates, servants, weapons and confidential companions.

Vishnu Sahastra Nama from the Mahābhārata

suvarṇa-varṇo  hemāṅgo  varāṅgaś  candanaṅgadi sannyāsa-kṛc chamaḥ śānto niṣṭhā śānti-parāyaṇam

For more quotes refer to this book which has over 100 shashtric quotations :-
https://www.purebhakti.com/resources/ebooks-magazines/bhakti-books/english/266-caitanya-mahaprabhu-the-original-form-of-godhead

Comment: Downvoted this has no reference towards to Chaitanya.

Comment: Which one has no reference?

Comment: Your quotes from the sb.

Comment: Those are references,  7.9.38- "chenna kalu", in kali yuga He is incognito avatara, and let me give u the context for- 11.5.32. ie:- 11.5.19 where Karabhajana muni replies for Nimi Maharaja's enquiry about the Yuga Avataras. 11.5.20-- " Śrī Karabhājana replied: In each of the four yugas, or ages — Kṛta, Tretā, Dvāpara and Kali — Lord Keśava appears with various complexions, names and forms and is thus worshiped by various processes." So therefore 11.5.32 is Karabhajan Muni's reply for the Avatara in Kali Yuga. Here also u can find the same explanation https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questio

Comment: This is the link, the above link dosent work 
    https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37320/what-are-the-scriptural-evidences-suggesting-chaitanya-mahaprabhu-was-the-incarn

Comment: That is a wrong interpretation: his name is not explicitly mentioned so you fill in the gap.

Comment: Interpretation is not by  me, but the Acharyas have said so, by the way,'not explicitly said' thats what 'chenna kalau' means in SB 7.9.38. Lol. At least u can accept that there is (yuga) Avatar in Kali yuga.  Also it is infered by other explicit sastric quotes from other puranas who 'that' avatar is. By the way even Chankya is not 'explicitly' said in SB 12.1.11, its 'inferred' by acahryas.

Comment: It depends on the sect. Other Acharya's disagree with you.